# How can I substract today date (or find interval id days) in a table?

Tags: sql, vertica

I am using Vertica SQL and have the following table:

```
CREATE temp TABLE XXX (DATE TEXT, PRICE INTEGER);
INSERT INTO XXX VALUES 
('2019-04-27 01:00', 1), ('2019-04-27 02:30', 3), ('2019-04-27 18:00',2), 
('2019-04-28 17:00', 2), ('2019-04-28 21:00', 5), 
('2019-04-29 17:00',50), ('2019-04-29 21:00',10), 
('2019-04-30 17:00',10), ('2019-04-30 21:00',20), 
('2019-05-01 17:00',40), ('2019-05-01 21:00',10), 
('2019-05-02 17:00',10), ('2019-05-02 21:00', 6);
```

I want to find a difference (compute in days) between today and dates in the table.
I tried to use

```
select (date_trunc('month',DATE)-date_trunc('month',current_date)) as DATE, PRICE from XXX
```

As I understood initial table has 13 rows, however date_trunc('month',current_date) has 1 row. As a result I have an error. How this issue can be solved?

And as I use Vertica should I add PostgreSQL or MySQL in tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with either `datediff` or `timestampdiff`

```
 datediff('day', date , Now()) as DaysBetweenDates

 timestampdiff(day, date, Now()) as DaysBetweenDates
```

Comment: @zealuous Thank you for your help, btw do you know how can I get a day difference only. With your code I also got a time, however only day is needed?

Comment: @JohnMayer instead of now, use `current_date` and see what are you getting.

Comment: @zealuous The same, it seems it comes from DATE in table XXX